# Perl: How to detect which file exists among foo.(txt|abc)

Tags: perl

My perl script needs to detect the extension of an existing file and print out the filename. The input that specifies the filename with a vague extension would be in this format:

```
foo.(txt|abc)
```

and the script would print "foo.txt" if it exists. If foo.txt does not exist and foo.abc exists, then it would print "foo.abc."

How can I do this detection and printing of the correct existing file in a neat and clean way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you've almost got the regular expression right there:  the only thing you need to do is escape the `.` with a backslash (since `.` means "any character except the newline character" in regular expressions), and it would also help to put a `?:` inside of the parentheses (since you don't need to capture the file extension).  Also, `^` and `$` denote markers for the beginning and the end of the string (so we're matching the entire string, not just part of a string...that way we don't get a match for the file name `"thisisnotfoo.txt"`)

Something like this should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1="foo.txt";
my $file2="foo.abc";
my $file3="some_other_file";

foreach ($file1,$file2,$file3)
{
  if(/^foo\.(?:txt|abc)$/)
  {
    print "$_\n";
  }
}
```

When the above code is run, the output is:

```
foo.txt
foo.abc
```

Take a look at [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for more stuff about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), but you'd have to use a different syntax.  The equivalent would be:

```
foo.{txt,abc}
```

See [File::Glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html) for more information.  Also note that this will return a list of all of the matches, so you'll have to do your own rules if it should prefer one when multiple exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub text_to_glob {
    my ($s) = @_;
    $s =~ s/([\\\[\]{}*?~\s])/\\$1/g;
    return $s;
}

my $pat = 'foo.(txt|abc)';

my @possibilities;
if (my ($base, $alt) = $pat =~ /^(.*\.)\(([^()]*)\)\z/s) {
   @possibilities =  glob(
      text_to_glob($base) .
      '{' . join(',', split(/\|/, $alt)) . '}'
   );
} else {
   @possibilities = $pat;
}

for my $possibility (@possibilities) {
   say "$possibility: ", -e $possibility ? "exists" : "doesn't exist";
}
```

- [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html), but also see [File::Glob](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aGlob)
- [-e](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

FILE:
for (glob "file.{txt,abc}") {
  if (-f $_) {
    print $_, "\n";
    last FILE;
  }
}
```